# How to select the <tr> that contains an input with attribute placeholder that's inside either named div

Tags: jquery

This may be really simple but I'm not all that familiar with jQuery selectors.

Here's the HTML with inline css:

```
<div id="login" style="position:relative; display:none; top:0px; left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; z-index:10;" class="trwhole">
    <table width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr width="100%" height="100%">
            <td width="100%" height="100%" style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;">
                <img src="images/MemorizeItWhite.png" z-index="10000" style="width:290px;">
                <table align="center" class="w290">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="lerror" class="alert"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Username:
                            <br>
                            <input autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" type="text" placeholder="username" id="username" style="" class="ui-corner-all w290">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Password:
                            <br>
                            <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" style="" class="ui-corner-all w290" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode==13){login();}">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" id="loginBt" onclick="login();" value="Log In" class="submit" style="width:85px;">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm looking for something like

```
$("select tr that contains input[placeholder] in #login or #signup2")
    .on("touchstart", function () { $("this > input").focus(); });
```

The point is to give each  an `ontouchstart` attribute changing focus to the input within it, if that input has a placeholder and is in either named div.

I could of course just add in the `ontouchstart` attribute to each tr manually, but then I wouldn't learn anything new, and I'm thinking this can be done with less code with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment problem, try:

```
$('#login tr:has(input[placeholder]), #signup2 tr:has(input[placeholder])')
   .on("touchstart", function (evt) { $(evt.target).filter("input").focus(); });
```

Comment: That is the selector, thank you! It seems that I'm failing on the second selector too though: $("this > input").focus(); any idea?

Comment: Try $(this).filter('input').focus();

Comment: Just so you understand... $('this') is a tag selector matching <this> elements, while $(this) returns a jquery object collection populated with the javascript variable *this*.  Make sense?

Comment: Sadly that doesn't do it. $(this) does return the tr jquery object:
[tr, context: tr, constructor: function, init: function, selector: "", jquery: "1.8.2"…]

Comment: Still not focusing on the input. And I thought the focus would be easy, oops.